# Do we have an "internal timer" when taking naps?

Tags: perception, sleep

I´m doing some research and can´t find what control some reactions during naps.

For example, after 1 year taking the same bus way home, my brain mastered the timing of napping. Wherever i get on, i start a nap and ALWAYS get up just before i have to get down the bus, it doesn´t matter if the nap took 5, 10, 25 or 50 minutes.

I think that maybe stimulations like sounds or body feelings of the road and environment are the triggers but can´t find information about it.

Also, i would like to distinguish it from the internal clock that concerns the whole day that regulates our lifestyle. (Circadian rhythm)

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking about napping on the bus during a ride or while waiting for the bus. I doubt you would get up after 50 minutes - this is when the body shifts into deeper sleep stages and causes sleep inertia, which is not really conductive to being aware of your bus stop.

Comment: There may be something in the bus route that your body is able to pick up on: several stops next to each other, a bumpy ride, a twisty road, some noise or smell? It's a skill many daily commuters pick up after a while.